# Finds no presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

As I write this in ViewController.m all well, but when I write it in a MyScene class, I get the error:
No visible @interface for 'MyScene' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'

```
   if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
    composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"text"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SKScene class doesn't implement presentViewController. You can only call this on a UIViewController subclass.

You need to get a reference to your containing view controller.

You can use "presentModalViewController" by using this code to access the root view controller

```
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc presentViewController: activityViewController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I had this problem in my app delegate and defining UIViewController *vc = self.window.rootViewController; solved the problem.